# Vb 2010 how to split (explode) a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Based on the code I provided I would like to explode a string into two. The code is working but only if `SearchQuery` contains two phrases.

```
Private Sub SearchTxt_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles SearchTxt.PreviewKeyDown
    Dim SearchQuery As String = SearchTxt.Text
    Dim MyString As System.String
    MyString = SearchQuery

    Dim OutPutArray() As System.String
    OutPutArray = Split(MyString, " ", -1)
    ''MsgBox(OutPutArray(0)) - Working

    MsgBox(OutPutArray(1)) ' error - Index was outside the bounds of the array.

end sub
```

Comment: Why not use `String.Split(" "c)`, rather than components from the old VB6 days?

Comment: Does your string contain a space?

Comment: @Salman, The aim is to slip from the space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is always zero based (every type of collection is), so `OutPutArray(1)` tries to access the second item not the first. If it contains only one you get the exception.

Instead you want: `OutPutArray(0)`

If you don't know if it contains two, check it:

```
Dim first As String = OutPutArray(0)
Dim second As String = Nothing
If OutPutArray.Length > 1 Then 
    second = OutPutArray(1)
End If
```

As an aside, i recommend to use .NET methods, so `String.Split`:

```
Dim OutPutArray As String() = MyString.Split() ' splits by white-spaces, tabs or newlines
```

or, if you only want to split by spaces:

```
 Dim OutPutArray As String() = MyString.Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: so am looking for both OutPutArray(0) and OutPutArray(1), in my case how can i do it

Comment: @user4649925: what you you tried? `If OutPutArray.Length > 1 Then second = OutPutArray(1)` does not give the error. But the the array is empty you get the exception at `OutPutArray(0)`. However, `String.Split` never returns an empty array.

Comment: `Dim MyString As System.String
            MyString = SearchQurry
            Dim OutPutArray As String() = MyString.Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            'MsgBox(OutPutArray(0)) - Working

            Dim first As String = OutPutArray(0)
            Dim second As String = Nothing
            If OutPutArray.Length > 1 Then second = OutPutArray(1)



            MsgBox(OutPutArray(1)) ' error is here`

Comment: Either the string is empty or not, it not suppose to give me an error. where am i getting you wrong?

Comment: @user4649925: you get the exception at `MsgBox(OutPutArray(1)` because it's not inside of the `If`. Use `If OutPutArray.Length > 1 Then second = OutPutArray(1) MsgBox(OutPutArray(1) End If`. If the string is empty `String.Split` returns an array that contains a single string which is `String.Empty`.

Comment: @user4649925: glad to hear that you've got it working. Edited my answer to replace the inline `If` with a multi-line `If`.